# Data transfer modifier obscures some of my Marked Sharp Edges

Tags: modifiers

I was following a tutorial on adding details to a panel. My panel is more curved than the instructors panel, so I added a data transfer to have better shading. When I add the data transfer, the panel marked edges don't look as good. The reason I add a data transfer is the Marked edges make hard edges on the topology.

As seen before and after in the examples, the first image has clearly more detail, and once the data transfer modifier is added, it fixes the shading issue, but it compromises the details.

[image]
[image]